# How to add client dependency

Tags: svelte, sapper

How to add client dependency to sapper?

I have a simple package that is transpiled to commonjs for portability.

My sapper project is using this dependency and is listed inside `package.json` (currently just pointing to a local directory):

```
"dependencies": {
    "foo": "./dependencies/foo"
}
```

To make sure all is working, I log out the module in `start.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import * as foo from "foo";
    console.log(foo);
</script>
```

When I run `sapper dev`, both the client and server compile, and the server is successfully logging the exports of this commonjs package:

[image]

However, when I start up the client in my browser on `localhost:3000`, the package is failing to load:

[image]

How do I fix this? Do I need to specify somewhere that my dependency needs to be made available to the client?

Note I am using the `commonjs` loader plugin which already exists in `rollup.config.js` from the sapper template.

This is basically the transpiled code of my package (transpiled using rollup):

`node_modules/foo/dist/legacy.cjs`:

```
exports.connect = async function() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: with the regular sapper template you can probably just use the module. Have you changed anything?

Comment: I don't think so no. I've been trying to find anything that I might have changed.

Comment: No differences for the client in `rollup.config.js`. Only differences in `package.json` is the version for sapper ^0.27.9 (instead of ^0.27.0) and svelte ^3.17.1 (instead of ^3.0.0)

Comment: Can you create a simple repro?

Comment: @RichHarris https://github.com/davidcallanan/sapper-issue

Comment: @RichHarris I've simplified the issue on the repo. Seems to be a problem with svelte build step or the svelte rollup plugin. Or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @RichHarris The problem seems to be that rollup or svelte does not support the [official node ESM system](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) added in node 13, which I am using in my package `foo`. I think it has a problem understanding `.cjs` files, but is still managing to pick them up.